# How to "catch" non-zero exit-code despite "set -e" then echo error code

Tags: linux, bash

I have script

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

if [[ ! $(asd) ]]; then
   echo "caught command failure with exit code ${?}"
fi

echo "end of script"
```

purpose of script is to terminate execution on any non zero command exit code with `set -e` except when command is "caught" (comming from Java) as in case of bad command `asd`

```
if [[ ! $(asd) ]]; then
   echo "caught command failure with exit code ${?}"
fi
```

however, though I "catch" the error and `end of script` prints to terminal, the error code is `0`

```
echo "caught command failure with exit code ${?}"
```

so my question is how can I "catch" a bad command, and also print the `exit code` of that command?

**edit**

I have refactored script with same result, exit code is still `0`

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

if ! asd ; then
   echo "caught command failure with exit code ${?}"
fi

echo "end of script"
```

Comment: `if ! asd; then
   echo "caught command failure with exit code ${?}";
fi`

Comment: @KamilCuk I added refactored script in edit, I still get same exit 0 though

Comment: @anubhava I added refactored script in edit, I still get same exit 0 though

Comment: `If the pipeline does not begin with the ! reserved word, the exit status shall be the exit status of the last command specified in the pipeline. Otherwise, the exit status shall be the logical NOT of the exit status of the last command. That is, if the last command returns zero, the exit status shall be 1; if the last command returns greater than zero, the exit status shall be zero.`

Comment: I'd strongly suggest being sure you've read and fully understand the content of [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises) before deciding to use `set -e`. It's not a well-designed feature, and can easily cause more bugs than it prevents.

Comment: Also, see https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/, comparing the wildly divergent ways different shells behave with `set -e` enabled; to summarize, it hurts not just predictability, but portability as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a short-circuit:

```
asd || echo "asd exited with $?" >&2
```

Or:

```
if asd; then 
    :
else
    echo asd failed with status $? >&2
fi
```

You cannot do `if ! asd`, because `!` negates the status and will set `$?` to 0 if `asd` exits non-zero and set `$?` to 1 if `asd` exits 0.

But note that in either case best practice is to simply call `asd`.  If it fails, it should emit a descriptive error message and your additional error message is just unnecessary verbosity that is of marginal benefit.  If `asd` does not emit a useful error message, you should fix that.

Answer (score 4):

> how can I "catch" a bad command, and also print the exit code of that command?

Often enough I do this:

```
asd && ret=$? || ret=$? 
echo asd exited with $ret
```

The exit status of the whole expression is `0`, so `set -e` doesn't exit. If `asd` succedess, then the first `ret=$?` executes with `$?` set to `0`, if it fails, then the first `ret=$?` is omitted, and the second executes.

Sometimes I do this:

```
ret=0
asd || ret=$?
echo asd exited with $ret
```

which works just the same and I can forget if the `&&` or `||` should go first. And you can also do this:

```
if asd; then
   ret=0
else
   ret=$?
fi
echo asd exited with $ret
```

Comment: The exit status of the whole expression is not relevant to `set -e` not exiting.  `set -e` will not force an exit in that case because a command that includes `&&` or `||` is one of several thousand special cases that `set -e` respects.

Comment: `The exit status of the whole expression is not relevant to set -e not exiting` - can you give examples? I feel like it is.

Comment: Try: `asd && false || false`

Comment: And exit status of the whole `asd && false || false` expression should always be 1. The exit status of `&&` and `||` is the exit status of the last command executed. So it will be, either way, `false` will be the last command executed. So the exit status of this whole expression will be 1, ie. nonzero, ie. set -e should raise ERR. Och I see, it's explicit in the description of `set -e`: "The shell does not exit if the command that fails is part of any command executed in a && or || list except the command following the final && or ||"

Comment: The exit status of the enitre expression is 1, but `set -e` does not cause the script to exit.  Because the exit status of the expression is irrelevant.